# Wercker - Ignore Branches on git push

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, wercker

Unfortunately [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38245032/wercker-possible-to-separate-build-tasks-per-branch) was not answered, but I think this is a related question.

I need to Ignore all Branches on a git push Pipeline except one (the master-branch). For chaining pipelines, when another pipeline finishes, you can specify `On branch(es)` --> specify exact one branch. But for a `git push` pipeline you can only `Ignore branches` with the comment: `Update which branches this pipeline doesn't trigger on`. So I want to Ignore all Branches except the master-branch. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is  a regular expression supported?

Comment: No doesn't seem so. I tried with `/^(master)$/`but now still pushes from e.g. `develop` are triggered